# Глобализация всех переменных в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, что у меня есть много переменных, которые создаются циклом:

```py
for i in range(1,6):
    exec('variable' + str(i) + '= i')
    exec('print(variable%s)' %str(i))
```

Затем, мне понадобилась 3 переменная:

```py
print(variable3)
```

Вывод программы:

```py
1
2
3
4
5
3
```

**Логично.**

Затем мне понадобилось цикл заключить в функцию:

```py
def variables():
    for i in range(1,6):
        exec('variable' + str(i) + '= i')
        exec('print(variable%s)' %str(i))
```

И снова вывести третью переменную, но на сей раз, выходит ошибка:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(variable3)
NameError: name 'variable3' is not defined
```

global? А если мне потребуется список с перечислением переменных? Делать так?

```py
global variable1
global variable2
global variable3
...
```

**Нет, глупо.**

global * (Что, по моему, логично) не работает!

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Не логично. Зачем вообще делать кучу переменных вместо одного списка?

Comment: К вышесказанному добавлю, что вместо глобальной переменной и функции следует использовать класс с методом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужна возможность получать данные из глобальной области, можно перенести их в локальную:

```
def a():
    # дополняем локальную область видимости
    locals().update({
        var:globals()[var] # помещаем в неё пару название_переменной:значение
        for var in globals() # которые берутся из глобальной области
        if var.startswith('variable') # если название переменной начинается с variable
    })
```

Если же речь идёт именно о механике объявления переменной как глобальной (чтобы при изменении её в функции она менялась в глобальной области видимости), вам придётся каждую переменную объявлять глобальной (`exec` тут не помощник, насколько мне известно)

А вообще это довольно посредственный подход к работе с данными, от которого лучше отказаться. 6 различных переменных в большинстве случаев можно заменить списком. Мне трудно представить ситуацию, в которой **такой** подход к работе с данными будет предпочтительным.

Comment: 6 различных переменных - просто пример, и не могли бы Вы уточнить части кода, просто я новичок и Ваш код мне не понятен

Comment: @SIMULACRA и, как я уже сказал, это очень плохой подход к хранению данных. Python разработан так, что он упрощает работу программиста, давая больше свободы выбора именно подхода решения задачи, чтобы не приходилось мучиться со сложным синтаксисом. Так зачем усложнять то, что сделано для упрощения?

Answer (score 2):

Можно обратиться к глобальном области видимости и зарезервировать там переменную. А дальше уже обращаться к ней из функции через глобальную область видимости.

```
def variables():
    for i in range(1,6):
        globals()['variable' + str(i)] = None;
        exec('variable' + str(i) + ' = ' + str(i), globals())
        exec('print(variable%s)' % str(i), globals())

variables()
print(variable3)
```

P.S. Но вообще это странное извращение, ведь большинство задач решаются и без подобного кода. Достаточно использовать список или словарь.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо кучи "нумерованных" переменных нужно использовать списки:

```
vars = []

for i in range(0,6):
    vars.append(i)  # добавить число в конец списка
    print(var[i])  # вывести значение по индексу
    print(var[-1])  # или вывести последнее значение в списке
```

Внутри функции:

```
def variables():
    vars = []
    for i in range(1,6):
        vars.append(i)
    
    return vars

print(variables()) # Выведет [1,2,3,4,5]
```